# GoogleMaps just show grey box

Tags: javascript, google-maps

As I remeber I used the google map code everytime like this ... but now it does not work anymore ... maybe I added an error, but I cant figure out.

Just a grey box is showed, but when take a look into the Dom of the google maps canvas I can see content and also when using methods like `map.getCenter()` I get the correct `lng` and `long` values.

Here is a fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tx8qhaho/
```

The map will be shown after 1.5sec because of the problem that the dom ready callback seems not to work in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry ... my fault ... I used the `<canvas>` tag but of course I have to use a normal `<div>` tag instead ...